# catchError not working with angular http interceptor used to mock error response

Tags: angular

I have a interceptor which mocks response as `return of(new HttpResponse({ status: 401, body: "Unauthorized" }));`

and a service code like

```
return this.http.post<string>(queryUrl,{ username, password },{ observe: 'response' })
.pipe(catchError(error =>{
  console.log("!!!!!!error in auth");
  return throwError("!!!!!!error in auth");
}
```

The catchError method is not being called with this setup though I expect it to. Is it not to be expected.

Comment: You return `of()`. That means you're sending a successful response. You need to return `throwError()`. https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/throwError

Comment: @JBNizet, even though the status is 401 or any other error status ? If the actual server returns this response, will the code then work?

Comment: The actual HTTP service, receiving a response from the server, will parse the response, inspect its status, and decide based on the status if the observable should emit an event or an error. But you're bypassing this service completely and mocking it. So you need to do the same thing it would do.

Comment: thats nice piece of information, though I expected angular http client to come into action after a response was returned from the interceptor.

Comment: How could you possibly get a response in your interceptor if the client doesn't provide it? **You** send a request, it goes through every interceptor, then finally to the actual http backend which sends the request transformed by the interceptor chain. Then the backend gets the response back from the server, emits it as an error or a success based on the satus, and it goes back to every interceptor in the chain, in reverse order, so that they can intercept/modify/act on the response.

Comment: @JBNizet wrong expectation from my side because using interceptor as backend is just a hack. thanks. pls log your answer.